# How to get routes from different routing files for different clients in express and node js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Two different clients have the same route in sever

client1_routes.js
client2_routes.js

Two files having the same routes but different implementations.
how to call different routes based on the client's request.

**Update**

Here is the Sample code

below is the contents from routes. for client1 and client2.

client1_routes.js

```
   router.route('/create_sample_lots')
    .post(auth, function(req, res) {
        
        upload_lots_service.createSampleLots(req,res);  
    });
```

client2_routes.js

```
router.route('/create_sample_lots')
.post(auth, function(req, res) {
    
    upload_lots_service.createSampleLots(req,res);  
    upload_lots_service.createNextLots();   
       
});
```

I need to call the above routes separately in a single app.

when I call routs from UI it always loading only a single route either the first one or the second one.

Comment: Have you used name spaces in your app?

Comment: add some code and explain your question what exactly you needed? Are you trying to say that you need to use different file on basis of request ?

Comment: @Jigar7521 we haven't used namespaces.

Comment: @Sasubelli Raki : Ok , but can yoju please do what Arif saying?